# Close all Dialogboxes when click ESCAPE(ESC) in primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am working with 4-5 primefaces dialogboxes. When click ESC i want close all dialogboxes which are opened.

Comment: This title and description makes sense because you specified the action (click) explicitly, but I have to admit that it's totally confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the dialog's `hide()` function through the client side object specified with `widgetVar`. So if you defined your `p:dialog` like:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog1" header="Dialog 1"/>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog2" header="Dialog 2"/>
```

Your ESC button should look like:

```
<p:commandButton value="ESC" onclick="dialog1.hide();dialog2.hide()"/>
```

You can also create a reusable `p:remoteCommand` to close all your dialog and use that in your `p:commandButton` or in `p:hotkey` - if by "click ESCAPE" you mean hittig the Escape button:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="closeAll" onsuccess="dialog1.hide();dialog2.hide()"/>
```

then in your components refer to the `closeAll()` command:

```
<p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="closeAll()"/>
<p:commandButton value="ESC" onclick="closeAll()"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the post is old, but the answer is rather a static solution, here's a dynamic one using jQuery.

```
function escDialog() {
   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 27) { // esc code is 27 
           closeAllDialog() ;
       }   
   });
}

function closeAllDialog() {
   for (var propertyName in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
     if (PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName] instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog ||
         PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName] instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.LightBox) {
         PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].hide();
     }
   }
}
```

Then in your document.ready you would call `escDialog()`

Hope this helps.